# Multiple buttons click effect handling

Tags: java, javafx

[image]

I would like to ask about two (or more) buttons handling using JavaFX.
On my project I have two Toggle Buttons. I want to assign to one of them a style (green round border) when it is pressed. When I'm clicking on another button, I want to delete the style from first one and move it to second button. Currently, I have situation that two buttons are visible as "pressed" at the same time (picture attached).
I would like to ask how to avoid this situation. Below is a code from my Controller file:

```
public void oneButton()
{
ToggleButton btn1=new ToggleButton();

    btn1.getStyleClass().add(".toggle-button:selected");
    


}
public void twoButton()
{
ToggleButton btn2=new ToggleButton();

    btn2.getStyleClass().add(".toggle-button:selected");
        
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of a `ToggleGroup`:

> A class which contains a reference to all Toggles whose selected
> variables should be managed such that only a single Toggle within the
> ToggleGroup may be selected at any one time [...] ([docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ToggleGroup.html)).

**ToggleGroupExampleApp.java:**

```java
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleButton;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleGroup;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class ToggleGroupExampleApp extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        // Create the toggle buttons:
        ToggleButton firstToggleButton = new ToggleButton("First Toggle Button"),
                secondToggleButton = new ToggleButton("Second Toggle Button");

        // Create a toggle group so only one toggle button can be selected at a time:
        ToggleGroup toggleGroup = new ToggleGroup();

        // Add the buttons to the toggle group:
        firstToggleButton.setToggleGroup(toggleGroup);
        secondToggleButton.setToggleGroup(toggleGroup);

        // Create a container:
        VBox vBox = new VBox(firstToggleButton, secondToggleButton);

        // Load a css file:
        vBox.getStylesheets().add(ToggleGroupExampleApp.class.getResource("styling.css").toExternalForm());

        // Prepare and show stage:
        stage.setScene(new Scene(vBox, 200, 100));
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

For styling purposes you can make use of the already available selected pseudoclass.

**styling.css:**

```css
.toggle-button {
    -fx-border-radius: 10;
    -fx-background-radius: 10;
    -fx-border-width: 2;
    -fx-pref-width: 180;
    -fx-pref-height: 35;
}
.toggle-button:selected {
    -fx-border-color: green;
}
VBox {
    -fx-spacing: 10;
    -fx-padding: 10;
}
```

***Edit (variation with FXML file and Controller class added):***

**Controller.class:**

```java
package org.example;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleButton;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleGroup;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class Controller implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private ToggleButton
            firstToggleButton,
            secondToggleButton;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        // Create a toggle group so only one toggle button can be selected at once:
        ToggleGroup toggleGroup = new ToggleGroup();

        // Add the buttons to the toggle group:
        firstToggleButton.setToggleGroup(toggleGroup);
        secondToggleButton.setToggleGroup(toggleGroup);
    }
}
```

**main.fxml:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ToggleButton?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<VBox spacing="10.0" stylesheets="@styling.css" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1"
      xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="org.example.Controller">
    <padding>
        <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0"/>
    </padding>
    <ToggleButton fx:id="firstToggleButton" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="35.0" 
                  prefWidth="150.0" text="First Toggle Button">
    </ToggleButton>
    <ToggleButton fx:id="secondToggleButton" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="35.0" 
                  prefWidth="150.0" text="Second Toggle Button">
    </ToggleButton>
</VBox>
```

**styling.css:**

```css
.toggle-button {
    -fx-border-radius: 10;
    -fx-background-radius: 10;
    -fx-border-width: 2;
}
.toggle-button:selected {
    -fx-border-color: green;
}
```

**ToggleGroupExampleApp.java:**

```java
package org.example;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;


public class ToggleGroupExampleApp extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(ToggleGroupExampleApp.class.getResource("main.fxml"));
        stage.setScene(new Scene(loader.load()));
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

Comment: works fine on Main class, although I am wondering how to implement the same with FXML and Controller class

Comment: Please have a look at my updated posting. I added a variation with a FXML file and a Controller class. Is it sufficient now for your needs?

Comment: perfect, I have implemented ideas from Your code to my project and it works :)

Answer (score -1):

How about something like:

```
ToggleGroup toggleGroup = new ToggleGroup();
ToggleButton toggleButton1 = new ToggleButton("Left");
ToggleButton toggleButton2 = new ToggleButton("Right");

toggleButton1.setToggleGroup(toggleGroup);
toggleButton2.setToggleGroup(toggleGroup);
```

Should let you add multiple buttons to the toggle group and it should clear the style off non-selected buttons when another is selected.

Comment: I think your ButtonClicked class is unnecessary.

Comment: Hello,
I have tested that one, it gives the same result as before.